# How do I pass multiple parameter arguments as a single variable to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**NOTE** I am not creating the inner_function - I am trying to call a specific function within mine and this seemed to be the easiest way to explain it without making is specific to the library I am using.

Here is what I am trying to do more specifically. This will be the two functions:

```
def inner_function(parameter1='nothing', parameter2='nothing', parameter3='nothing'):
    print(parameter1)
    print(parameter2)
    print(parameter3)

def outer_function(parameter_set=<default value>):
    inner_function(parameter_set)
```

First, when I call `outer_function()` I expect the output to be:

nothing

nothing

nothing

I do not know what the `<default value>` should be to accomplish this.

Second, if I want the output to be:

nothing

wamo

thunk

What would the argument passed into `outer_function()` be?

Sorry if this is explained in a confusing manner or has been asked before but I am having trouble finding a post answering this.

I have not tried much for the default value - only None and empty []

Comment: It might make sense to use keyword arguments.  That way you can specify only the arguments you want to provide, and automatically pick up the default values for the others.

Comment: `inner_function(parameter_set)` This passes one **and only one** argument. 
`parameter_set` will be passed as `parameter1`.  Nothing at all will be passed as `parameter2` and `parameter3`, so those will receive their default values.

Comment: Are you able to use the `**kwargs` syntax for calling `inner_function()`?  Or are you locked in to the example you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said in the comments, you can use **keyword arguments**:

```py
def inner_function(parameter1='nothing', parameter2='nothing', parameter3='nothing'):
    print(parameter1)
    print(parameter2)
    print(parameter3)

def outer_function(parameter_set={}):
    inner_function(**parameter_set)
```

Some tests:

```
>>> k1 = {"parameter2": "foo"}
>>> k2 = {
...  "parameter1": "YEs",
...  "parameter2": False,
...  "parameter3": (1,2,3),
... }
>>> inner_function()
nothing
nothing
nothing
>>> outer_function()
nothing
nothing
nothing
>>> outer_function(k1)
nothing
foo
nothing
>>> outer_function(k2)
YEs
False
(1, 2, 3)
```

Just remember that anything can get passed in the `kwargs` variable, if you want to limit it to your variables, you should add some code in `outer_function` to check it before running `inner_function`

Comment: This is the right answer. My only suggestion is that your usage example would be even better if you showed that some of the arguments could be omitted from the dictionary in order to still get the default values (i.e. show that you can do `outer_function({"parameter2": "wamo", "parameter3": "thunk"})`, which the questioner asked for).

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll edit `k1` to do this.